# Play with numbers problem from hackerearth ....i'm getting time limit exceed problem

Tags: java

You are given an array of n numbers and q queries. For each query you have to print the floor of the expected value(mean) of the subarray from L to R.

***Input***:

First line contains two integers N and Q denoting number of array elements and number of queries.

Next line contains N space seperated integers denoting array elements.

Next Q lines contain two integers L and R(indices of the array).

***Output***:

print a single integer denoting the answer.

***Constraints***:

1<= N ,Q,L,R <= 10^6

1<= Array elements <= 10^9

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlayWithNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        long n=obj.nextLong();
        long qry=obj.nextLong();
        long arr[]=new long[(int) n];
        for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
            arr[i]=obj.nextInt();
        }
            for (int j = 0; j <qry ; j++) {
                long sum=0;
                double ans=0;
                int L=obj.nextInt();
                int R=obj.nextInt();
                sum=(L+R)/2;
                ans=Math.floor(sum);
                System.out.println((int) ans);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: your solution is wrong. The question clearly is stating that **L** and **R** are the indexes of the subarray (not the value), and you are using as value to find the mean value.

**Second**: Scanner class is very easy, need less typing but not recommended as it is very slow. Instead, use **BufferReader**.

Here is my solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PlayWithNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( 
                              new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()); 
        long n=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
        long qry=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
        long arr[]=new long[(int) n];
        st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()); 

        // read every number, adding with previous all numbers and store in the array index
        arr[0] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
        for (int i = 1; i <n ; i++) {
            arr[i]=arr[i-1]+Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <qry ; j++) {
            long sum=0;
            double ans=0;
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()); 
            int L=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
            int R=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 

            // check if the value 1 then don't subtract left value (as in that case there won't be any left value
            // otherwise subtract just left most value from the array
            if (L == 1) {
                sum=arr[R-1]/(R-L+1);
            } else {
                sum=(arr[R-1] - arr[L-2])/(R-L+1);
            }
            ans=Math.floor(sum);
            System.out.println((int) ans);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Thanks Sir, its working fine...and i actually don't see that we have to take L and R as indices .